# Symfony2 bypassing default locale in parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony, service, translation, locale

i am newbee in Symfony2.
I'm wondering if it is possible to override default hardcoded locale in parameters.yml and set one i.e from a @service ??

The task is to manage languages and locales from admin area (e.g. added and stored in database). And to use default one, based on this data.

I've tried to use LocaleListener described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html
but anyway it takes %default_locale% from parameters for the first request.

Also, there are a lot of nice bundles for route translations as JMSI18nRoutingBundle
and LexikTranslationBundle for translations, but all of them use in configuration hardcoded %default_locale% and/or locale lists.

Is it possible to solve this somehow with Symfony2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you register your LocaleListener service in services.yml? The example in the cookbook is supposed to work.